# ZIP determinated folders in a directory

Tags: c#, compression, zip

I want zip determinated folders.

Actually I have a folder named  MyFolders, and behind I've multiples folders and files, and I would use CreateFromDirectory method but zip all, but only I want zip 2 folders: "Tools" and "Data".

Due to this, I create a temporary directory and use CreateFromDirectory, but I don't want copy the same folders to other location in the disk (almost, the zipped already folders is better).

So, is it possible?

I want do something like this:

```
ZipFile my_zip;
my_zip.AddDirectory("Tools");
my_zip.AddDirectory("Data");
```

but in the .Net Framework 4.5.1, and without external libraries.

Thank you very much!